# Git - find staged files with unstaged changes

Tags: git

I wish to detect if a staged file has unstaged changes, and add this to a pre-commit hook.

For example, when the output is like this, I should be able to detect that README.md has unstaged changes.

```
❯ git status

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    modified:   README.md

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   README.md
    modified:   foo.txt
```

The best solution I could find is to write the list of staged and unstaged files into files, and use `comm`

```
git diff --name-only > /tmp/unstaged.txt
git diff --name-only --staged > /tmp/staged.txt
comm /tmp/unstaged.txt /tmp/staged.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use short status, staged content shows up as `M` in the first column, non-staged content as `M` in the second column. Thus detecting files with staged and non-staged changes can be done with

```
git status -s | awk '/MM / { print $2 }'
```

Comment: Works great, thank you!